# Extended Surface Definition

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

As a surface S is an $\mathbb{R^3}$ subset that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$. Given any metric space $\mathbb{M}$ does it have any interest to define a surface S as an $\mathbb{M^3}$ subset that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{M^2}$?

Is I see it, as $\mathbb{M}$ is a metric space it is a topological space. Also being metric provides a distance so the concept of geodesic curve among S keeps having sense.

I would like to know what problems may appear when extending the definition of some $\mathbb{R^3}$ surfaces concepts to a more generic metric space. And also if this "generalized surfaces" are being studied or have any interest for any specific metric space $\mathbb{M}$.

Comment: The first problem you get is that (unlike $\mathbb{R}^n$) not all spaces are homogenous. Meaning your "locally homeomorphic" notion depends on the choice of a point/neighbourhood in $\mathbb{M}$. This makes things a lot more complicated. Also the case of $\mathbb{M}$ being a normed space seems to be the only interesting one. Those other cases may be studied by someone, but it is a rather rare practice.

Comment: Some work has been done for rationals $\mathbb{M}=\mathbb{Q}$ ([see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207205/differential-topology-over-mathbbq)), which is a homogenous space, but unfortunately over $\mathbb{Q}$ everything trivializes.